# How to reset developer account password?

Tags: change-password, ringcentral

I have received a developer account number and extension, however I never received the email with the password.  I can't reset it from the test portal either as it is asking me a security question.  I tried to answer based on my actual account, but it says invalid.

Obviously, I can't do anything until I get this password.  So what are my options?  Create a new app and hope it works the second time?  I checked my mail server and don't see any rejected emails from RC either.

Edit: Looks like the email was rejected.  It failed SPF, the server doesn't have rDNS, and I guess it got knocked a point for having the From header Base64 encoded.

Anyway, how can I reset it?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please create a support case at :

[RingCentral Developer Support](https://developer.ringcentral.com/support.html)

One of the team members would be able to assist you with resetting the Developer Account password.